Equality arising from coinciding of $R^2$ with slope of regression of predicted vs observed values
If I am able to interpret this correctly, then in the accepted answer to Does the slope of a regression between observed and predicted values always equal the $R^2$ of the original model? it is proven that there is an equality between the $R^2_{XY}$ measurement corresponding to a linear regression of the form $Y = \alpha_{XY} + \beta_{XY} X + \varepsilon_{XY}$, with the estimation $\widehat{\beta}_{Y\widehat{Y}}$ of the slope in the regression equation $\widehat{Y} = \alpha_{Y\widehat{Y}} + \beta_{Y\widehat{Y}}Y + \varepsilon_{Y\widehat{Y}}$, where $\widehat{Y}$ is the prediction of $Y$ based on the first regression equation.
Given that there is also an equality for $\widehat{\beta}_{Y\widehat{Y}}^2$ of the form
$$
\widehat{\beta}_{Y\widehat{Y}}^2 = \rho_{Y\widehat{Y}}^2\left(\frac{s_\widehat{Y}}{s_Y}\right)^2 = R_{XY}^2\left(\frac{s_\widehat{Y}}{s_Y}\right)^2
$$
does this then always imply that
$$
\widehat{\beta}_{Y\widehat{Y}} = \left(\frac{s_\widehat{Y}}{s_Y}\right)^2\,?
$$
